# How to escape $ sign in serverless yaml config?

Tags: amazon-web-services, yaml, aws-api-gateway, serverless-framework

I want to escape $ sign when using [stage variables](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/aws-api-gateway-stage-variables-reference.html) for api gateway.

Following error appears when I try to deploy.

> Invalid variable reference syntax for variable stageVariables.capabilitySecurityUrl.
>   You can only reference env vars, options, & files. You
>   can check our docs for more info.

I have tried following options, but not working

1) Using Without Quotes 
  Uri: https://${stageVariables.capabilitySecurityUrl}

2) Using with quotes
  Uri: "https://${stageVariables.capabilitySecurityUrl}"

3) Access variable from file

```
./stageVariables.json
{
   "capabilitySecurityUrl":"https://${stageVariables.capabilitySecurityUrl}"
}

./serverless.yml
${file(./stageVariables.json):capabilitySecurityUrl}
```

Any help?

Comment: i realize this is old, but did you ever figure this out? having the same issue

Comment: If I remember correctly, I changed syntax of variable.
https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables#using-custom-variable-syntax

Let us know if this works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As author said, customizing variableSyntax worked for me:

```
  # notice the double quotes for yaml to ignore the escape characters!
  # Use this for allowing CloudFormation Pseudo-Parameters in your serverless.yml
  # e.g. ${stageVariables.my_var}. All other Serverless variables work as usual.
  variableSyntax: "\\${((?!stageVariables)[ ~:a-zA-Z0-9._@'\",\\-\\/\\(\\)]+?)}"
```

https://www.serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#using-custom-variable-syntax

Answer (score 1):

You can try using the [Cloudformation Join function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/intrinsic-function-reference-join.html):

```
Fn::Join: ['', ['https://$','{{stageVariables.capabilitySecurityUrl}}']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Escaping variables is now natively supported by *Serverless*

https://github.com/serverless/serverless/issues/3565

> Closing, as escaping is supported by a new resolver, e.g `\${self:}` will be taken literally